# Локализация. Падение при определении языка устройства

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d

Пишу игру на `cocos2d-x` под андроид. Сделал себе локализацию по примеру с [этого сайта](http://amanita-studio.com/ru/articles/read/cocos2d-x-localized). Все работало, но в один прекрасный день я решил обновить версию `cocos2d-x` с `3.3` до `3.10`.

Там есть строка `LanguageType langKey = Application::getInstance()->getCurrentLanguage();`, которая определяет язык устройства. В новой версии кокоса программа начала падать на этой строке с `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000001c (code=1)`. В версии `3.3` все работало нормально.

В связи с этим вопрос - как это исправить и какие еще есть способы определения языка устройства в `cocos2d-x 3.10`?

Comment: А чему равно у вас `Application::getInstance()`? Не `null` часом?

Comment: Проверил, не `null`. Падает на `getCurrentLanguage();`

Comment: Пройдите внутрь `getCurrentLanguage()` отладчиком, возможно прояснится.